# Overwrite the file if already exists

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

need to overwrite a file if already exists. in following line of codes Using Adobe api to convert pdf to excel. however, need to overwrite a file if the file already exist in a location (boresult command)

```
Dim objAcroApp      As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim objAcroAVDoc    As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim objAcroPDDoc    As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim objJSO          As Object
Dim boResult        As Boolean
Dim ExportFormat    As String
Dim NewFilePath     As String
'Initialize Acrobat by creating App object.
Set objAcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

'Set AVDoc object.
Set objAcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
'Set the PDDoc object.
Set objAcroPDDoc = objAcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc

'Set the JS Object - Java Script Object.
Set objJSO = objAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject
   'some code to define newfilepath format function; confidential so not 
    sharing
    'Save PDF file to the new format.
    boResult = objJSO.SaveAs(NewFilePath, ExportFormat)
    'need boResult to overwrite if file already exists.
```

Comment: You can use `kill FilePath & FileNam` to delete an already existing file.

Comment: Thanks @Damian works